Post not carrying out when called in a onclick event handler
I made a program just for fun updating user emails
I make a function which i have tried to place inside event handler outside tried everywhere, that function has a post request and it returns true if it got a response and false if it catches a error
I am trying to do a while loop but it doesn't carry out tasks. I got it working once but don't know how
The important part is where checkCookieValid is a function it accepts paramaters cookie, username and it sends a post request, sends the cookie and username in a object then if it gets a response it sets the function to return true I suppose and if it catches error, false then outside of it I try to as you know use the while loop but its not running the code inside?
var checkCookieValid = (cookie, username) => {
  axios
    .post(
      "http://localhost:3000/sendCookielist", {
        cookie: cookie,
        username: username
      }, {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      },
    )

    .then((response) => {
      if (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        return true;
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err.response) {
        console.log(err.response);

        return false;
      }
    });
};
while (checkCookieValid(Data.current.cookie, Data.current.username) === false) {
  console.log("helo");
}


"sorry if i formatted it badly" - There's an edit feature which will allow you to correct this.  Additionally, please also clean up the description of the problem to be more specific about which operation in your code isn't doing what you expect.

my problem is pretty simply explained ok? i don't know how to simplify it further, it is when i use a function in if statement and check if the function returns true or false, it only carries out the function in the code inside the () of if statement but nothing in the curly braces

Your problem is not explained simply, was filled with filler words and explanation formatted as code. Why are you console logging like that in a while loop and running this check infinitely? What other logs are you getting in the console? What is the surrounding code that you mention?

sorry that is just something i tried, that wasnt my main objective it was that nothing works in there except for the function, and yes true my post is filled with filler words im new to stackoverlfow and it was asking me to write an essay for a small problem forgive me

it wasn't originally supposed to do it infinitely i would have called the function inside it again but with different arguments and if the user entered the cookie and its valid this time, the latest function would set the new cookie to orginal cookie's place in a object

The problem is likely that you are expecting the function "checkCookieValid" to be executed synchronously but it is actually asynchronous.
var checkCookieValid = (cookie, username) => {
  // the function will return (undefined) before axios.post has finished executing
  axios.post( ... )
  ...

You need to use either async and await, return a Promise or use a callback mechanism.
Using a Promise could work like this:
var checkCookieValid = (cookie, username) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  axios
    .post( ... )
    .then((response) => {
      if (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        // return will not work here
        resolve(true);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err.response) {
        console.log(err.response);
        // same here
        resolve(false);
      }
    });
})

Then you need either an async environment:
async function main () {
  // with a loop
  var isValid = false;
  do {
    const isValid = await checkCookieValid(Data.current.cookie, Data.current.username);
  } while (isValid === false)
  
  // or without a loop
  const isValid = await checkCookieValid(Data.current.cookie, Data.current.username);
  if (isValid === false) { ... }
}

or you can use then (without a loop):
checkCookieValid(Data.current.cookie, Data.current.username)
  .then(isValid => { ... })


if by synchronously  you mean that the function runs after ? that is what i want but if you don't mind and forgive a newbie here, but why is the function asynchronous?

Thanks it just worked there not sure how since i don't understand this

Also can i use a return div thing inside the loop in async function? or does it not return anything like promise?

Nevermind i got the component rendering working through states
